# Wordpress is stripping parameters from URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url

My Wordpress site is stripping parameters from the URL. This is detrimental to tracking google adwords and bing ads because they rely? bunchofparameters to be appended to the URL.

I tried looking in the redirect plugin and the `.htaccess`, but all the `.htaccess` has is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I think you should go to the wordpress admin panel and in setting menu you got the setting of permalinks .

Comment: i tried switching the permalinks back and forth and that didn't work.....

Comment: What do you mean by "stripping parameters from the URL"? What URL, and when does it do it?

Comment: http://www.micreditlawyer.com/identity-theft/?exampleparameter

Comment: if you go to that link you will see the ? and everything after it gets stripped away

Comment: Have you got any additional plugins installed that manage 404's, Permalinks or other link related functions? It's not default WordPress behaviour to strip this.

Answer (score 1):

To get a custom querystring in a URL, you need to make Wordpress aware of it first. Wordpress does some complex URL rewriting and for security, it also strips out any parameters it doesn't recognize.

You'll need to create an action on `init` which calls `add_rewrite_tag()` one or more times to register the custom queryvars you need.

See the [add_rewrite_tag Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) for details.

Comment: I have to add parameters to be allowed? Wouldn't there be a setting that gets rid of all stripping?

Comment: If there is a way, I haven't found it, and I've been looking for this for years.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The wordpress site I was managing had a Wordpress SEO plugin that had "Redirect ugly URL's to clean permalinks. (Not recommended in many cases!)" checked. This was what was stripping my query parameters!

Comment: Was this the Yoast plugin, and were you trying to track for Google Analytics purposes? I may have run into the same issue.